# Problem solving a simple integral equation

Tags: calculus

Could someone help me finding q(t) so that

\begin{equation}
\int_x^{x+2\pi/3}q(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = a\cdot\sin{(x)}+b
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My try: 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}q\left(v+x\right)\,\mathrm{d}v = a \sin{x}+b 
\end{equation}

In the other hand:

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{3xa}{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{xv}{2\pi/3}\right) dv=a\sin\left(x\right)$$

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{b}{2\pi/3} dv=b$$

Then:

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}q\left(v+x\right)\,\mathrm{d}v= \int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{3xa}{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{xv}{2\pi/3}\right) dv+\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{b}{2\pi/3}dv$$

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \left( q\left(v+x\right)-\frac{3xa}{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{xv}{2\pi/3}\right)-\frac{b}{2\pi/3} \right) \,\mathrm{d}v=0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Could you check what I just found?

\begin{equation}
q(x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\cos{\left( x+\frac{\pi}{6} \right)}
\end{equation}

verifying : 
\begin{equation}
\int_x^{x+2\pi/3}q(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = a\cdot\sin{(x)}+b
\end{equation}
got the feelin it's a bit too easy...

Comment: it's perfect! you need the constant $b$ yet and a minus sign. http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e8hpp95oaa2

Comment: $$q(x)=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+\frac{3b}{2\pi}$$ would do the job http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1cu4ma8ie

Comment: great!!! it works!

Comment: no, look the link I sent you

Comment: haha thanks again that was usefull!!

Comment: you're welcome.